# Delete duplicate records from SQL Server 2012 table with identity

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to replicate a scenario where I need to delete all duplicate rows from a table except one. But all rows have a unique identity column.

For making things easier, I created a small test table student and the script is as below.

```
create table student 
(
    id int,
    rollno int,
    name varchar(50),
    course varchar(50)
)
GO

insert into student values(1,1335592,'john','biology')
insert into student values(2,1335592,'john','biology')
insert into student values(3,1335592,'john','biology')
insert into student values(4,1335592,'john','biology')
insert into student values(5,1335593,'peter','biology')
insert into student values(6,1335593,'peter','biology')
insert into student values(7,1335593,'peter','biology')
GO

select * from student
```

This will generate the table as below.

```
id  rollno  name    course
1   1335592 john    biology
2   1335592 john    biology
3   1335592 john    biology
4   1335592 john    biology
5   1335593 peter   biology
6   1335593 peter   biology
7   1335593 peter   biology
```

I would like to keep the records with ID '1' and '5' in the result set and delete everything else. Is there any way to do this?.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Shammas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple query

```
Delete from student 
where id not in (select min(id) 
                 from student 
                 group by rollno, name, course)
```

Comment: Thanks Ullas..It worked for me.. After posting the question I found the link  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/01/sql-server-delete-duplicate-records-rows/ where it is well defined.  Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4):

Use `CTE`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as
(
  select rn=row_number() over
  (
     partition by rollno,name,course
    order by id
  ),*
  from student
)
delete from cte 
where rn > 1;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3666f/1)

Comment: Thanks wanderer. This script is also correct. Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

you can Use
[DENSE_RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173825.aspx),
[ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ,[RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176102.aspx)

these all'll give you the result.

Try:

```
create table student 
(id int,
rollno int,
name varchar(50),
course varchar(50)
)
GO

insert into student values(1,1335592,'john','biology')
insert into student values(2,1335592,'john','biology')
insert into student values(3,1335592,'john','biology')
insert into student values(4,1335592,'john','biology')
insert into student values(5,1335593,'peter','biology')
insert into student values(6,1335593,'peter','biology')
insert into student values(7,1335593,'peter','biology')
GO



;with cte as
(
  select rn=row_number() over
  (
     partition by rollno,name,course
    order by id
  ),*
  from student
)
select * from cte where rn=1

;with cte2 as
(
  select rn=RANK() over
  (
     partition by rollno,name,course
    order by id
  ),*
  from student
)
select *  from cte2 where rn=1

;with cte3 as
(
  select rn=Dense_RANK() over
  (
     partition by rollno,name,course
    order by id
  ),*
  from student
)
select *  from cte3 where rn=1
```

See [Difference between ROW_NUMBER(), RANK() and DENSE_RANK()](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823497/What-is-the-Difference-between-ROW-NUMBER-RANK-and)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE s
FROM student s
JOIN student s2 ON s.course = s2.course
     AND s.NAME = s2.NAME
     AND s.rollno = s2.rollno
WHERE s2.id < s.id
```